# Searching for "-<>" in the contents of files

Tags: spotlight

There is a coding library [Swiss Arrows](https://github.com/rplevy/swiss-arrows) that uses the operator **-<>** for a particular operation.

I don't seem to be able to search for this in the contents of files on a mac.

Is there a particular trick I need to do to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to use Spotlight on Mavericks (10.9.2) to search for a test text file containing the `-<>` pattern and it worked.

I used `"-<>"` as my search pattern (including the double quotes) and it found the test file.

Comment: One other idea is to use `mdfind` command in Terminal.app, which is the command-line interface for Spotlight and give you a little finer control. `man mdfind` for details on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

EasyFind might do it [untested for that particular string] - Freeware from the App Store.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion - but it doesn't appear to work for this string.

Comment: I just tested it on a sample text file on desktop & it found it. I have the left column set to ... file contents; Phrase; Ignore Case; Package Contents & Invisible. Search term was just -<> [SE trying to throw me by adding this dash